# create .ttf (true type font) file programmatically

Tags: truetype

I'm interested in creating my own .ttf file using my own code. I did some research and found Apple's specification for .ttf files.
I'm having trouble understanding it though.  Here is an excerpt:

"A TrueType font file consists of a sequence of concatenated tables. A table is a sequence of words. Each table must be long aligned and padded with zeroes if necessary." https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6.html

I opened up a .ttf file with notepad++, expecting to see the tables described above, but just got a bunch of incomprehensible stuff. See attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

My question: What are these tables?

Can anybody expand on what I need to do to create these tables? I'm newer to writing code, so maybe the problem is my lack of coding knowledge. If that's the case, could someone point me to a reference where I can educate myself on these tables?

Comment: The specification is referring to a "table" as a programmatic table set up in the language of your choice. Use Java, or C/C++, Python, Ruby, VBA to open the `.ttf` file and read the data in the file into a table variable you set up in the program. That's the easiest way to work with it. It sounds like you're expecting to open the `.ttf` file and view as you would a MSWord document. It's a data file and doesn't work that way.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Am I correct to think then that I can read the data in the .ttf file into a table variable and then output that data to a text file? (I'm looking for a way to see an example of how .ttf files are structured, so that i can read apple's spec on one screen and have an example on the other.)

Comment: I'll be using java by the way.

Comment: You can certainly read the ttf in java, then format the table data and write the formatted output to a human readable file. It's a worthy programming exercise. I've not looked, but there may be a ttf file data viewer app you could find that would do what you want.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. And good idea on the .ttf viewer. I'll definitely look around for something like that.

Comment: "... you're expecting to open the .ttf file and view as you would a MSWord document" actually has the same problem: you need to open it *with an application that understands the format*. That said: you can make a good start by reading the main structure; that way you can pick out any sub-table you want, and write specific code for each. See [its description in the specs](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/otff.htm#otttables).

Comment: Is there a way for me to open up an existing .ttf file and see it's format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question:

http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hexdump.htm

I uploaded a .ttf file here and the site converted it to hexadecimal form to display. Now i can read the .ttf specification in one window and have an example of the spec being implemented up in another.

Originally i was looking for a binary display, but this hex display is much better for viewing.

Using this hex dump along with the .ttx file makes the .ttf file format a LOT more understandable.

Update:

I found another answer. There's a python package called 'ufo-extractor' that converts .otf or .ttf files into .ufo files. A .ufo file is a human readable font file. See:
http://unifiedfontobject.org/

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [OpenType Cookbook](http://opentypecookbook.com/) about how to program fonts. If you want to simply take a look at the tables you mentioned, you'll need a tool like [TTX/FontTools](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools) to convert the binary tables to something more readable (an XML file in this case).

Comment: Thanks! The .ttf/ttx converter was very helpful to get a look at what's in the .ttf file.